# WindRiver - eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

In the "ifconfig" I don't see eth0 appears.

When I tried to type:

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

I got the following message

```
eth0: PHY ID 200xx5c99 at 1 IRQ ) (stmmac-1:01) active
```

And when I typed:

```
cat /etc/udev/ruled.d/70-persistentnet.rules
```

I got the following message

```
# PCI device 0x8086:0x0937 (stmmaceth)
SUBSYSTEM=="net" , ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:22:97:55:ff:b8", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",ATTR{type}=="1",KERNEL=="eth*",NAME="eth0"
```

I dont get any idea why eth0 does not appear,please let me know if you may have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical reason why `ifconfig` does not show an interface is because this interface is not in the "UP" state, and the typical (again) reason for this is that the interface does not have an IP address.

For `ifconfig` to "display all interfaces which are currently  available, even if down" (quoting the man page), use `ifconfig -a`.

Comment: I also did ifocnfig -a. I got eth2 but eth0. Any further advise ?